# PyQt5 Progress Bar is not progressing 0% to 99% (Python 3.9 _ QThread_YouTube video downloader)

Tags: python, pyqt, progress-bar, qthread, python-3.9

I am trying to make a YouTube Downloader with a progress bar. I am using a separate class for downloads and the Progress bar. My progress bar is updated by the  “ProgressBar1” method from “thedownload_thread” class.

The problem is progress bar is not updating while downloading is going on.

From download start to end
[image: From download start to end]

But As soon as the video downloading finished progress bar is showing 100%

[image: downloading finished]

*This is the “download_thread” class that I used to calculate the value for the progress bar. I didn’t get any errors in the code.*

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from pytube import YouTube

from Thread_Checks_yVideo import Thread_ChecksV


class download_thread(QThread):
    progressCount = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.MainCode = parent

    def run(self):
        index = self.MainCode.comboBox_Quality_1.currentIndex()
        path = self.MainCode.lineEdit_2.text()
        name = self.MainCode.lineEdit_3.text()
        link = self.MainCode.lineEdit.text()

        if index == 0:
            try:
                print("Starting to Download 720p....")
                self.MainCode.label_Vcomplete.setText("Starting to Download 720p")

                video = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=self.ProgressBar1)
                
                video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(output_path=path, filename=(name + ".mp4"))

                print("Downloading Finished 720p....")

            except:
                self.MainCode.label_Vcomplete.setText("An Error is Occurred 720p")

        elif index == 1:
            try:
                print("Starting to Download 360p....")
                self.MainCode.label_Vcomplete.setText("Starting to Download 360p")

                video = YouTube(link, on_progress_callback=self.ProgressBar1)
                
                video.streams.get_lowest_resolution().download(output_path=path, filename=name + ".mp4")

                print("Downloading Finished 360p....")

            except:
                self.MainCode.label_Vcomplete.setText("An Error is Occurred 360p")


    def ProgressBar1(self, stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
        
        total_size = stream.filesize

        bytes_download = total_size - bytes_remaining
        liveProgress = int((bytes_download / total_size) * 100)

        self.progressCount.emit(liveProgress)

        if liveProgress == 100:
            print(".....Labeled")
            self.MainCode.label_Vcomplete.setText("......Download Finished.....")
```

This is the main class that I used to build the project.

```
import Design
import requests
import traceback
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from pytube import YouTube

from Thread_Checks_yVideo import *

from Thread_Downloads_yVideo import *

class MainCode(QMainWindow, Design.Ui_Downloader):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainCode, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Thread_Checks_yVideo = Thread_ChecksV(self)
        
        self.Thread_Downloads_yVideo = download_thread(self)
       

        self.setWindowTitle('YouTube Downloader')
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Download.jpg"))
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setdefault()
        self.handlebuttons()

        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)

    def handlebuttons(self):
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.openVdownload)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.openPdownload)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.facebook)
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.about)

        self.pushButton_Go_1.clicked.connect(self.Thread_Checks_yVideo.start)
        self.pushButton_6.clicked.connect(self.browseV)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.DownloadVZ)

        

    def setdefault(self):
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setVisible(False)
        Q = ['High Quality', 'Low Quality']
        self.comboBox_Quality_1.addItems(Q)
        self.comboBox_Quality_2.addItems(Q)

        self.label_Vcomplete.setText("Add a video URL to Download............... ")
        self.label_Title.setText("Title of Video :")
        self.label_Views.setText("Views :")
        self.label_Rating.setText("Rating ")
        self.label_Duration.setText("Duration :")
        self.label_Count.setText("Video Count :")
        self.label_Pcomplete_1.setText(" ")
        self.label_Pcomplete_2.setText("Add a PlayList URL to Download................ ")
        self.progressBar_1.setValue(0)
        

    def browseV(self):
        try:
            file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select Directory"))
            self.lineEdit_2.setText(str(file))

        except:
            self.label_Vcomplete.setText("An Error is Occurred")

    
    def DownloadVZ(self):
        self.pushButton_4.setDisabled(True)
        self.Thread_Downloads_yVideo.progressCount.connect(self.onCountChangedPBar1)
        self.Thread_Downloads_yVideo.start()

    def onCountChangedPBar1(self, progressCountPBar1):
        self.progressBar_1.setValue(progressCountPBar1)
        
    def openVdownload(self):
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


    def about(self):
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(3)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainCode()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am using "DownloadVZ" method to connect the progress. "onCountChangedPBar1" is used to set value to the progress bar.

Can anyone help me to overcome this issue?
Any help would be much appreciated....

*(I have tried to use “QApplication.processEvents()” instead of QThread. But it didn’t work out either.)*

Comment: You cannot update *any* UI element from external threads, you *must* use signals for that (make a custom signal that emits the text you want for `label_Vcomplete` and then connect it in the main window class to `label_Vcomplete.setText`). Then, assuming that is not the cause of the problem (but it might be), have you tried to just `print(liveProgress)` in `ProgressBar1()`?

Comment: Yes I have tried to print " liveProgress" in the ProgressBar1().But, it didn't work out.

Comment: *What* doesn't work out? Make yourself more clear: does it print the progress? doesn't it print anything? Also, you're not using caching and setting already existing target files, are you?

Comment: Actually, when I tried to print the progress values, only the last value ( that means  100) was printed. and also, I am not using caching and setting for already existing targeted files.

Comment: You didn't answer the last question: did you check if the file already exists? By default pytube skips existing files: see the `skip_existing` argument of [`download()`](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download).

Comment: Actually, l am giving a new name to downloading file each time . So, I didn't uesd '''skip_existing''' method.

Comment: Actually, when I try to download a video, it is downloading without a error. Only problem is the progress bar. It is not showing progress until the downloading finished.

Comment: You're not answering the question. The fact that you're using a different name is irrelevant: are you *completely sure* that the file does not exist (including the fact that it matches the size)? If the file exists, it doesn't return an error.

Comment: Yes . I am totally sure the file doesn't exist.